# JavaScript: Guarantee object initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I have a code running that initializes an abstraced graph package. After creating the graph instance I get the data with a get request from the server and want to update the graph dataproviders. Problem is that sometimes (for IE6-8) the object that holds the dataprovider is not initialized yet, so the javascript crashes when I try to update the data.

How can I do a delay of the code until the object is ready?
Pseudo:

```
...
...
...
// Init code
$graph = new Graph();
...
...
...
// GET request
$.getJSON(..., ..., function(data) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  // Make sure that $graph.series[0] is ready
  // Should not use while, but something similar in functionality
  while (!($graph.series && $graph.series[0]))
    ; // Sleep the code until object is ready

  // Set the dataprovider after init complete
  $graph.series[0].setData(data);
  ...
  ...
  ...
});
...
...
...
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Rather than your `while` loop (as you identified, not quite what you want), use a `setTimeout`.

```
$.getJSON(..., ..., function(data) {
    processData();
    function processData() {
        if (!($graph.series && $graph.series[0])) {
            // Not ready yet, schedule to try again in a moment
            // and quit
            setTimeout(processData, 0);
            return;
        }

        // It's there, process
        $graph.series[0].setData(data);
    }
});
```

The delay will be more than `0` milliseconds, of course (typically no less than 5-10), but it gives other code a chance to initialize that object for you. You might want to add a timeout so you don't loop forever if something has gone wrong.

It may seem odd that we can still access `data` even after our callback from `getJSON` returns, but we can because `processData` is a *closure* over the callback's context, so it has an enduring reference to everything in scope within that context (including `data`). More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar couple of days ago. In this code I am verifying that object *gAuto* was initialized with needed property. Hope it helps.

```
function check(callback) {
    if (gAuto.hasOwnProperty('gm_accessors_')) {
        callback();
    } else {
        console.log('waiting for init');
        init(callback);
    }
}

function init(callback) {
    console.log('initializing');
    setTimeout(function() {
        check(callback);
    }, 1);
}

init(function() {
    console.log('init done!');
            // access 'gm_accessors_' here
});
```